# работа с HTMLEvents для проверки длины строки ввода текста input не больше 10

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать функцию которая будет проверять постоянно что поле input не больше 10 елементов,сделать хочу через обработчик собитий,как поставить условия в функции?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);" onchange="checkLength(this);" placeholder="Enter data" >

function checkLength(obj) 
    {
      var element = document.getElementById('t');
          var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
          e.initEvent('change', false, true);
          element.dispatchEvent(e);
          alert("ivalid length - 10 characters only!");
          return element;
    }
```

Comment: Так у вас уже ограничение в атрибуте `maxlength` стоит

Comment: Стоит смотреть в сторону `t.value.length`